# How I can index this query for free text search

Tags: postgresql, pg-search

Hi dear postgres users,

Short story, I have a Address table related to a State (each Address has a State). To I will run the following query for a search:

```
SELECT "addresses".*, (ts_rank((to_tsvector('simple', coalesce("addresses"."name"::text, '')) || to_tsvector('simple', coalesce(pg_search_85240c410826a2b0e0f0e5.pg_search_442c4ad3183a256248ef8d::text, ''))), (to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || 'test' || ' ''' || ':*')), 0)) AS pg_search_rank 
FROM "addresses" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT "addresses"."id" AS id, string_agg("states"."name"::text, ' ') AS pg_search_442c4ad3183a256248ef8d 
            FROM "addresses" INNER JOIN "states" ON "states"."id" = "addresses"."state_id" GROUP BY "addresses"."id") pg_search_85240c410826a2b0e0f0e5 ON pg_search_85240c410826a2b0e0f0e5.id = "addresses"."id" 
            WHERE (((to_tsvector('simple', coalesce("addresses"."name"::text, '')) || to_tsvector('simple', coalesce(pg_search_85240c410826a2b0e0f0e5.pg_search_442c4ad3183a256248ef8d::text, ''))) @@ (to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || 'test' || ' ''' || ':*')))) AND (company_id = 2142) 
            ORDER BY pg_search_rank DESC, "addresses"."id" ASC
```

Straight forward, right? This takes about 1.226ms on a good machine and a 8581 addresses. I need to improve this, so I create this 2 indexes

```
CREATE INDEX index_addresses_search_by_name ON addresses USING gin(to_tsvector('simple', COALESCE((public.addresses.name)::text, '')))
CREATE INDEX index_state_search_by_name ON states USING gin(to_tsvector('simple', COALESCE((public.states.name)::text, '')))
```

This should help, create a index on Addresses and a index on States, but it does not :( The query is slow as before and *explain* shows the indexes are not being used.

Please offer a suggestion,

EDIT:

Here is what explain analyze will show:

```
"Sort  (cost=11.39..11.40 rows=1 width=4824) (actual time=0.947..0.947 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  Sort Key: (ts_rank((to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, COALESCE((public.addresses.name)::text, ''::text)) || to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, COALESCE((string_agg((states.name)::text, ' '::text)), ''::text))), '''test'':*'::tsquery, 0)), public.addresses.id"
"  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 17kB"
"  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=6.19..11.38 rows=1 width=4824) (actual time=0.905..0.905 rows=0 loops=1)"
"        Join Filter: (public.addresses.id = public.addresses.id)"
"        Filter: ((to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, COALESCE((public.addresses.name)::text, ''::text)) || to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, COALESCE((string_agg((states.name)::text, ' '::text)), ''::text))) @@ '''test'':*'::tsquery)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on addresses  (cost=0.00..5.14 rows=1 width=4792) (actual time=0.904..0.904 rows=0 loops=1)"
"              Filter: (company_id = 2142)"
"        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=6.19..6.20 rows=1 width=520) (never executed)"
"              ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.02..6.18 rows=1 width=520) (never executed)"
"                    Hash Cond: (public.addresses.state_id = states.id)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on addresses  (cost=0.00..5.11 rows=11 width=8) (never executed)"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=1.01..1.01 rows=1 width=520) (never executed)"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on states  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=520) (never executed)"
"Total runtime: 1.226 ms"
```

Edit2

Addresses ddl

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;

SET search_path = public, pg_catalog;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_with_oids = false;

--
-- Name: addresses; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: trucking; Tablespace: 
--

CREATE TABLE addresses (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying(255),
    street character varying(255),
    city character varying(255),
    zip_code character varying(255),
    primary_phone character varying(255),
    alternate_phone character varying(255),
    fax character varying(255),
    email character varying(255),
    contact character varying(255),
    company_id integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    motor_carrier_number character varying(12),
    state_id integer,
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone,
    alternate_phone2 character varying(12),
    insurance_expires_on date,
    notes text
);


ALTER TABLE public.addresses OWNER TO trucking;

--
-- Name: addresses_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE; Schema: public; Owner: trucking
--

CREATE SEQUENCE addresses_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;


ALTER TABLE public.addresses_id_seq OWNER TO trucking;

--
-- Name: addresses_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE OWNED BY; Schema: public; Owner: trucking
--

ALTER SEQUENCE addresses_id_seq OWNED BY addresses.id;


--
-- Name: id; Type: DEFAULT; Schema: public; Owner: trucking
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY addresses ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('addresses_id_seq'::regclass);


--
-- Name: addresses_pkey; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: trucking; Tablespace: 
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY addresses
    ADD CONSTRAINT addresses_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);


--
-- Name: index_addresses_on_company_id; Type: INDEX; Schema: public; Owner: trucking; Tablespace: 
--

CREATE INDEX index_addresses_on_company_id ON addresses USING btree (company_id);


--
-- Name: index_addresses_on_state_id; Type: INDEX; Schema: public; Owner: trucking; Tablespace: 
--

CREATE INDEX index_addresses_on_state_id ON addresses USING btree (state_id);


--
-- Name: index_addresses_search_by_city; Type: INDEX; Schema: public; Owner: trucking; Tablespace: 
--

CREATE INDEX index_addresses_search_by_city ON addresses USING gin (to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, COALESCE((city)::text, ''::text)));


--
-- Name: index_addresses_search_by_email; Type: INDEX; Schema: public; Owner: trucking; Tablespace: 
--

CREATE INDEX index_addresses_search_by_email ON addresses USING gin (to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, COALESCE((email)::text, ''::text)));


--
-- Name: index_addresses_search_by_name; Type: INDEX; Schema: public; Owner: trucking; Tablespace: 
--

CREATE INDEX index_addresses_search_by_name ON addresses USING gin (to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, COALESCE((name)::text, ''::text)));


--
-- Name: index_addresses_search_by_street; Type: INDEX; Schema: public; Owner: trucking; Tablespace: 
--

CREATE INDEX index_addresses_search_by_street ON addresses USING gin (to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, COALESCE((street)::text, ''::text)));


--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

States DDL

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;

SET search_path = public, pg_catalog;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_with_oids = false;

--
-- Name: states; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: trucking; Tablespace: 
--

CREATE TABLE states (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    abbrev character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    country character varying(255)
);


ALTER TABLE public.states OWNER TO trucking;

--
-- Name: states_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE; Schema: public; Owner: trucking
--

CREATE SEQUENCE states_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;


ALTER TABLE public.states_id_seq OWNER TO trucking;

--
-- Name: states_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE OWNED BY; Schema: public; Owner: trucking
--

ALTER SEQUENCE states_id_seq OWNED BY states.id;


--
-- Name: id; Type: DEFAULT; Schema: public; Owner: trucking
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY states ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('states_id_seq'::regclass);


--
-- Name: states_pkey; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: trucking; Tablespace: 
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY states
    ADD CONSTRAINT states_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);


--
-- Name: index_states_search_by_abbrev; Type: INDEX; Schema: public; Owner: trucking; Tablespace: 
--

CREATE INDEX index_states_search_by_abbrev ON states USING gin (to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, COALESCE((abbrev)::text, ''::text)));


--
-- Name: index_states_search_by_name; Type: INDEX; Schema: public; Owner: trucking; Tablespace: 
--

CREATE INDEX index_states_search_by_name ON states USING gin (to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, COALESCE((name)::text, ''::text)));


--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

Best rewrite so far

```
SELECT consolidated_address.id, (ts_rank((to_tsvector('simple', coalesce(consolidated_address.name::text, '')) || to_tsvector('simple', coalesce(consolidated_address.state_name::text, ''))), (to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || 'Gallaway' || ' ''' || ':*')), 0)) AS pg_search_rank 
FROM (
 SELECT "addresses".id,
    "addresses".name,
    string_agg("states".name::text, ' ') as state_name
    FROM addresses
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "states"
    ON "states".id = "addresses".state_id
    GROUP BY "addresses".id) consolidated_address
WHERE 
    (((to_tsvector('simple', coalesce(consolidated_address.name::text, '')) || to_tsvector('simple', coalesce(consolidated_address.state_name::text, ''))) @@ (to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || 'Gallaway' || ' ''' || ':*'))))
```

It's a little faster but still does no use any of the indexes

Thank you,

Comment: For future questions please make sure to show your Pg version, and for slow query questions the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT .... your query ....`. See https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: Have you `ANALYZE`d your table after index creation? Can we see the DDL of the involved tables and constraints, please?

Comment: Your question says that it takes 282 ms to run the query, but the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output shows a run time withing the PostgreSQL server of 1.226 ms. How did you arrive at the 282 ms timing?

Comment: Sorry @kgrittn I've must have done copy/paste typo there

Comment: The estimated cost for the plan is very low, and it is running in about 1 ms. Is this the actual problem, or do you have an example of a run which is actually slower? If the latter, please show *that* query and its `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` results.

Comment: Dear @kgrittn this is the actual query that is running slow

Comment: Any chance you are running it through a prepared statement? That would result in a generic plan, based on table averages, whereas a query with the search arguments plugged in as literals will choose a plan based on those particular values. Or are you trying to get a run time below 1 ms for this query?

Comment: As a simple note, the db name is postgres, not postgre.

Comment: Also I read the plan as follows:  It plans two sequential scans and prunes one of them out.  The other scan returns 0 rows and takes extremely little time.  This suggests to me that the table is small enough that the planner figures using an index is just a waste of time.

Comment: @ChrisTravers fixed typo, thank you for pointing this out

Answer (score 1):

Answer cross-posted from Github at https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search/issues/51

I'm the author of the [pg_search](http://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) Ruby gem that generated this query.

---

Yeah, unfortunately I don't know of a way to get :associated_against queries to work against an index, at least the way things are currently implemented.

It's because :associated_against searches against all of the associated records' text joined together, rather than on a single record at a time basis.

So for instance if you joined into a tags table, and there are 3 records ("foo", "bar", and "baz"), then you would expect a search for "foo baz" to find it. The more easily indexable solution would only work for "foo" or "baz" queries, but not "foo baz", because no one of individual tags rows matches both terms, if you know what I mean.

It's not possible to index across multiple records (at least to my knowledge).

Maybe we could surface an option in pg_search to do the search record-by-record, which could use the index, but not match across records.

Comment: I would like to see a skillful sql dude rewriting this query if there is a way

Comment: If there is a way to do it, let me know and I'll update pg_search to use that way instead.

Answer (score 1):

My reading of your explain analyze output is that your table is too small to profit from using an index.  Sequential scans on PostgreSQL are relatively cheap because the table is loaded as a physical file and PostgreSQL can take advantage of OS prefetching and the like.

Keep in mind that no plan is faster than loading a single page from disk and scanning through it sequentially.  Using an index will just add overhead.  It's no taking any significant time on the sequential scan and so don't worry about that until you have real data to play with.

It is worth noting that on PostgreSQL, optimizing queries before you have data is a recipe for more problems than solutions.  My sincere recommendation is wait to analyze the query until you have a real one returning real data.  Then we can determine which indexes will help or not.

Edit: You say the query is slow. But the plan shows it being executed in 1ms. How much time do you expect it to take?

Answer (score 0):

This query is slow because the query you are joining to via left outer join is using aggregating the entire address table then restricting by company_id. Does the address table have a company_id? Try moving the where clause to the inner query to restrict the number of records returned.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this does no explain why is the index not used

Comment: btw, I will +1 this answer if can you please rewrite the query with your suggestion.